# Replace a pixel value in an image (numpy) to the closest color in a dict

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, optimization

I have an image with 4 channels rgba but I only want to compute the difference of rgb of each pixel and replace it with the closest color in a dict.

```
myMap = {
    'a': ([255, 27, 255, 255]),
    'b': ([255, 255, 27, 255]),
    'c': ([255, 27, 27, 255]),
}
```

Let this be my array,

```
np.random.seed(seed=777)
s = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(3, 4, 4))
print(s)
```

This is how I replace the pix but it is very inefficient because 3 loops are used.

The logic is to loop over every pixel and calculate the distance with every value in the dict, then replace the value by the one in dict for that particular pixel.

After running the function, the image shd consist of 3 colors only at most.

Is there a better way achieve what I want?

```
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    for j in range(s.shape[1]):
        _min = math.inf
        r, g, b, _ = s[i][j].tolist()
        for color in myMap.values():
            cr, cg, cb, ca = color
            color_diff = math.sqrt((r - cr)**2 + (g - cg)**2 + (b - cb)**2) 
            if color_diff < _min: 
                _min = color_diff
                s[i][j] = np.array([cr, cg, cb, ca])

print(s)
```

Comment: "and replace it with the closest color in a dict." - why does it matter (why should it be helpful) that the colors are in a dict? What is the rule that tells you, how close a given color is to the pixel's color?

Comment: As each color represents an obj in my case. So it would be more readable if i define it in a dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little bit vague. Do you want to improve the performance or readability?

Readability can be improved by making use of additional dimensions and fancy indexing:

```
import numpy as np

# Use array instead of dictionary (np.array(list(myMap.values()))
myMap = np.array([[255, 27, 255, 255],
                  [255, 255, 27, 255],
                  [255, 27, 27, 255]])

np.random.seed(seed=777)
s = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(3,4,4))

# Determine color differences (Use additional dimension)
cdiffs = np.sum((s[:,:,None,:]-myMap)[...,:-1]**2,axis=-1)**0.5

# Get the indices of the closest value
idx = np.argmin(cdiffs,axis=-1)

# Extract closest value to assemble array (Fancy Indexing)
s = myMap[idx]

print(s)
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Improves readability, performance, is shorter in a good way (even with comments), and true to the spirit of both Python and numpy.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks I learnt a new thing about additional dimensions .

Comment: @balu, if you are interested in further material, I can recommend numpy's documentation on [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: This solution is brilliant. May I ask one follow-up question? how does `s[:,:,None,:]-myMap` work?

Comment: Or why `s-myMap` doesn't work?